# Zip key value pairs in python

Tags: python

I need to change my output from number 1 = 0 to (1:0) or ('1':0). I want to change to key value pair. Below is the code I'm using.

```
numberlist = [1]
val_list = [0]
for (number, val) in zip(numberlist, val_list):
    print 'number ', number, ' = ', val
```

output: `number 1 = 0`
desired output is: `('1':0) or  (1:0)`

Comment: You can use `dict(zip(numberlist,val_list))` if you want a dictionary.

Comment: i want a dictionary to use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
numberlist = [1, 2, 3]
val_list = [4, 5, 6]

mydictionary = dict(zip(numberlist,val_list))
```

This will create a dictionary with `numberlist`as the key and `val_list` as the value.

```
>>> mydictionary
{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
>>> mydictionary[1]
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formatted print statement to achieve this:

```
numberlist = [1]
val_list = [0]
for (number, val) in zip(numberlist, val_list):
    print "(%d:%d)" % (number, val, )
```

to print (1:0), or

```
numberlist = [1]
val_list = [0]
for (number, val) in zip(numberlist, val_list):
    print "('%d':%d)" % (number, val, )
```

to print ('1':0)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm a fan of the splat operator.

```
numberlist = [1, 3, 5]
val_list = [0, 2, 4]
for fmt in zip(numberlist, val_list):
    print("('{}':{})".format(*fmt))
```

Keep in mind that each item in each list is an integer, but is being printed with quotes. If you actually want to convert each to a string, you can do something like:

```
newList = zip(map(str, numberlist), val_list) # List of tuples
# or, if you want a dict:
newDict = dict(newList) # dict where each key is in numberlist and values are in val_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in dict function after zip. This will give you a dictionary and then you can iterate over the dictionary to obtain a key value pair.

```
numberlist = [1]
val_list = [0]    
print dict(zip(numberlist, val_list))
```

Comment: This appears to use Python 2 syntax